# How to disable the annoying pop-up window after automatic updates are installed on Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, windows-update, popups

I'm running Windows XP SP3. After automatic updates are installed, there shows up an annoying pop-up window every 10 minutes that tells me whether I want to restart the machine now or later. This interrupts my work as it pops up in the middle of an important process.

I don't want to disable automatic updates. I just want to disable this annoying pop-up window and restart the machine without having to see this warning. Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Short answer from Lifehacker:](http://lifehacker.com/289998/disable-windows-update-restart-nag)

> - To stop this service, open [Command
>     Prompt] (Start>Run>cmd>Enter)
> - Type the following command **sc stop
>     wuauserv**.
>
> This will not prevent
>   Automatic Updates from starting at the
>   next boot. So don't worry, you'll keep
>   getting Windows updates. Just don't
>   forget to restart eventually.

[or try:](http://lifehacker.com/software/top/get-rid-of-windows-update-restart-nag-183976.php)

> Now, to get rid of it:
>
> - Start
> - Run
> - gpedit.msc
> - Local Computer Policy
> - Computer Configuration
> - Administrative Templates
> - Windows Components / Windows Update
> - Re-prompt for restart with scheduled installations

[Jeff has a post](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/000294.html) with some more explanations around it if you're interested

Comment: Any ideas for non-admins? http://superuser.com/questions/152302/how-can-i-get-rid-of-the-annoying-windows-automatic-update-needs-reboot-popup-as

Comment: This works great. I usually just suspend the process using process explorer.